# Python failing to load boost.python dll

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost-python

I'm having some problems with a trivial boost python setup.
I have seen a lot of other people have had problems, but none of them seem to be the same issue as mine, as none of their resolutions worked.
For reference, I am on windows 10, using mingw64 10.2 as part of msys2 for my c++ compiler. I built boost using that compiler for debug and optimised, and I built a dll linking against boost.python with that compiler as well.

my Cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
 
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development) 
include_directories(${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})


set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE -x64)
set(Boost_NO_WARN_NEW_VERSIONS ON) 
# set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/Devel/install/include/boost-1_76")
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR "C:/Devel/install/lib")
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
add_definitions("-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK")
add_definitions("-DBOOST_UUID_USE_SSE2")
add_definitions("-DBOOST_UUID_USE_SSE3")
add_definitions("-DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB")
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:/Devel/install/include")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "C:/Devel/install/lib")

find_package(Boost 1.76.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS python39)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE PythonBindings_SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/PythonBindings/*.cpp")
add_library(PythonBindings SHARED ${PythonBindings_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(PythonBindings Boost::python39 Python3::Module)
set_target_properties(PythonBindings PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX PREFIX "" SUFFIX ".pyd" IMPORT_PREFIX "" IMPORT_SUFFIX ".pyd.a")
target_compile_definitions(PythonBindings PRIVATE EXPORT_PYTHONBINDINGS)
```

Cpp file:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* 
helloWorld()
{
  return "Hello, world!";
}

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PythonBindings)
{
  def("hello_world", helloWorld);
}
```

This successfully compiles to 'PythonBindings.pyd'. Opening this in dependency walker, I can see it exports the symbol 'PyInit_PythonBindings'

When I try use this dll from python (`python -vv py/helloworld.py`)

```
import PythonBindings;

PythonBindings.hello_world()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Devel\Working\test\py\helloworld.py", line 18, in <module>
    import PythonBindings;
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1173, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing PythonBindings: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am not sure what the problem is. My $PATH variable contains the search paths for all the dependencies of PythonBindings.pyd (libboost_python39-mgw10-mt-x64-1_76.dll, kernel32.dll, MSVCRT.dll, libgcc_s_seh-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll, python39.dll)

I named the dll the same as the python module, which I know some people have had trip them up, and I used the same c++ compiler and python version for building boost and my library, and I used the same python version for linking both of those as I did for running my python script.

I'm all out of ideas on how to fix this issue.

Comment: You may want to give a try to [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find out where dll's are used from. Other installations on python which are on search path may cause troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the tutorial [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560816/Troubleshooting-dependency-resolution-problems-usi) following doqtor's comment, and found that the problem was python not loading several dlls that were runtime dependencies of PythonBindings.pyd.

This was fixed by adding

```
import sys
import os
[os.add_dll_directory(dir) for dir in sys.path if os.path.isdir(dir)]
```

before `import PythonBindings`

It's very odd to me that python doesn't search sys.path for dll dependencies. The paths that it needed to search were also on os.environ['PATH'], but again it didn't search them. I'm not sure if there is a nicer way to do this. I would like to hear about it if there is.